# Scrolling dynamically to the end of the page

Tags: jquery, scroll, toggle

I have a link which animates some `div`'s height when its hovered, but the `div` has a big `height` and it goes beyond the visible bottom-end of the screen.

I have to scroll to see the data and when I scroll I leave the hover area and the div toggles it's `height` to `0px`.

How to automatically scroll to the end of the `div` when it toggles?

Comment: Its hard to give a better answer without some example code but try adding this to your CSS:  div {overflow:scroll;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `scrollTop` property of the body:

```
// Scroll all the way to the bottom
document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the DIV's [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) property to it's [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/), e.g.:

```
$("#theDiv").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).scrollTop($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: It's interesting how we both read the question differently.  I thought he wanted to scroll the body to get the bottom of the div in view, but really either of us could be right :-)